# Prediction with accelerated failure time in r for clinical data

Tags: classification, predictive-models, recurrent-events

So I have the following problem and I want to discuss it with you to see if I am thinking correctly.

**Data description:**

I have recurrent data from clinical trial. The data has a specific `mtest` that is performed each year to indicate disease degree `scale`. The `mtest` can be ranged as `1:5`. So I have about `60,000` records that represent `10,200` patients, because some patients have more than one record (recurrent data). Data set records have the following format `ID, start, stop, scale, mtest`.

***Data Sample***
Here is a sample from the data

```
ID start stop mtest scale
1     7    8      1   0
2     2    3      1   0
2     3    4      1   0
2     4    5      1   0
2     5    6      1   1
2     6    7      1   0
2     7    8      1   0
3     2    3      1   0
3     3    4      1   0
3     4    5      1   1
3     5    6      2   1
3     6    7      1   0
4     1    2      1   0
4     2    3      1   0
4     3    4      1   0
4     5    6      1   0
4     6    7      1   0
4     7    8      1   0
5     2    3      1   0
5     3    4      1   0
5     4    5      1   0
```

may be this sample not reflect the exact nature of the data, because, as I said before, `mtest` ranged from `1` to `5`.

***Goal***

I want to use `mtest` covariant to predict the `scale` for next years.

**Progress**

I read some articles and posts about survival analysis and according to my understanding that I can use `PH` (Proportional Hazard) to specify the hazard  or `AFT` (Accelerated Failure Time) to predict time for event (correct me if I am wrong). So from the above understanding, I will use `AFT`.

I used `r`, below what I have:

```
Sur <- Surv(test$start, test$stop, test$scale, type='interval')
model <- survreg(Sur ~ mtest +cluster(ID) , data = test, dist =      'w'); summary(model1)
```

and the summary for above model as shown below

```
Call:
 survreg(formula = Su ~ mtest + cluster(ID), data = test, 
    dist = "w")
             Value Std. Err (Naive SE)     z         p
 (Intercept)  2.691   0.0274     0.0223  98.3  0.00e+00
 mtest       -0.307   0.0139     0.0124 -22.1 4.92e-108
 Log(scale)  -1.320   0.0239     0.0181 -55.3  0.00e+00

 Scale= 0.267 

 Weibull distribution
 Loglik(model)= -8210.4   Loglik(intercept only)= -8474.8
     Chisq= 528.78 on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0 
 (Loglikelihood assumes independent observations)
 Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 8 
 n= 25191
```

Then I used `predict` function from `r` as follow

```
pre <- predict(model)
```

which gave me the following results :

```
 [1] 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148
 [11] 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148
 [21] 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148
 [31] 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148
 [41] 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148
 [51] 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148  7.987366 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148
 [61] 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148
 [71] 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148  7.987366 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148
 [81] 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148
 [91] 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148 10.853148
**snipped
```

***Questions***

1) **The summary**: as you can see from the summary that the model produce `-0.307`, so why its negative and what is the proper interpretation for it?

2) **Predict function results**  : the result from `predict` function does not make any sense. Let say that the follow-up for the patients is from `2000` to `2017` how can I predict the `scale` value for year `2020` for specific patient. For example I used the following 
    casedat <- list(mtest=1, Id= 'Id90')
    pr=1:99/100
    pre <- predict(model, newdata = casedat)

which gave me

```
> pre
        1 
 10.85315
```

so what `10.85315` means.

Many thanks in advance with appreciating to all your comments.

Comment: where is your scale variable?

Comment: Sorry @DeepNorth its an `event`, I will edit this too

Answer (score 3):

I think if you can give more detail of your dataset  there are a lot of people in this site can help you.

You say "The data has a specific mtest that is performed each year to indicate disease degree scale" and from your code below:

```
 Surv(test$start, test$stop, test$scale, type='interval')
```

The above code shows that $scale$ should be the indicator variable to indentify whether the subect had an event or censored.i.e sacle should be a dummy variable with value $0$ or $1$. You can type $?Surv$ in R to check. Also you have a interval censor type data here.

```
Surv(time, time2, event,
type=c('right', 'left', 'interval', 'counting', 'interval2', 'mstate'), origin=0)
```

Your $Goal$ is "use mtest covariant to predict the $scale$ for next years" i.e to predict yes or not (for the scale variable).

I hope I understand you well.

However, what you did is to predict survival time of a subject, not the "event" of the subject.

Since I don't have your dataset, let us use [Stanford heart transplant data](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/heart.html) to show how to do the prediction.

```
 heart$start<-heart$start+0.1 #for weibull can not run with zero I add 0.1

 Sur<-Surv(heart$start, heart$stop, heart$event,type="interval")

 model<- survreg(Sur ~ age+year,data= heart,dist="w") 

 summary(model)
```

The results are:

```
 Call:
survreg(formula = Sur ~ age + year, data = heart, dist = "w")
             Value  Std. Error     z        p
(Intercept) 1.53398     0.4807 3.191 1.42e-03
age         0.00701     0.0304 0.231 8.17e-01
year        0.56026     0.1454 3.854 1.16e-04
Log(scale)  0.75931     0.0846 8.975 2.84e-19

Scale= 2.14 

 Weibull distribution
 Loglik(model)= -272.6   Loglik(intercept only)= -280.6
    Chisq= 15.85 on 2 degrees of freedom, p= 0.00036 
 Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 7 
 n= 172
```

Now let use predict

```
   pre <- predict(model)
```

The results are

```
 [1]   4.404946   5.493280   5.623295   5.623295   5.779412   5.779412   
5.385467   7.191498
  [9]   7.324740   7.324740   7.266231   7.450016   7.232708   7.232708   
7.562176   7.562176
 [17]   8.250926   8.356734   8.356734   8.336692   8.336692   8.415050   
        8.532549   8.532549
[25]   6.978359   9.070038   9.070038   9.459353  10.283023  10.283023   
     9.501070   9.501070
 [33]  10.140262  10.140262  11.734231  11.734231  11.450256  11.450256  
  ....
```

These are just 172 predicted times for each sujbect.

Let check subject 1's survival time, we use his age =-17.15537303, and year=0.12320329 to predict his/her survival time.

```
  p1<-predict(model, newdata=data.frame(year=0.12320329,age=-17.15537303),type="response")
  p1
```

Note we specified type="response" here.

The result is

```
   > p1
   1 
  4.404946
```

Which is exactly the survival time.

Now you can see for your data, what you predicted is survival time,i.e. the "response" not the event.

Also, I think you can not predict an event, but you can predict a probability of an envent during a period of time. I think you need specify type='qunatile'.

I think if you have a right censored data the prediction seems much easier to understand. I am even not sure what the prediction is for the interval censored data.

The meaning of coefficient of -0.307 can be seen from the weibull model:

$log(T)=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\sigma\epsilon$ suppose your mtest is continuous varialbe.

$log(T_1)=\beta_0-0.307(x+1)+\sigma\epsilon
\\log(T_0)=\beta_0-0.307x+\sigma\epsilon\\\Rightarrow log(T_1)-log(T_0)=-0.307$

This means when x increase by one unit the survival time decrase -0.307 days on log scale (suppose your time is measured by days)

You also can see $log(\frac{T_1}{T_0})=-0.307$ this also shows that when mtest increase by 1 unit the survival time will be shorter.

The explanation has a opposite direction with the Cox model.

Comment: Thank you @DeepNorth. I did add a sample from my data, hope this can make things more clear. Now what `4.404946 ` means? is it mean "that we expect that patient p1 will survive for **4.404946**  unit of time", and what is the meaning of the negative sign `-0.307`  that shown in the summary in my code

Comment: See my edited answer